# Display/hide control in Webpart based on edit/browse mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a Visual Studio project in which I have created a Visual Webpart. In the user control I have a panel which I want to display in edit mode and hide in browse mode.

ASP.NET code snippet:

```
<asp:panel runat="server" ID="myControl">
```

C# code snippet in user control code behind:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    WebPartManager wpm = WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(this.Page);
    if (wpm.DisplayMode == WebPartManager.BrowseDisplayMode)
    {
        myControl.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none");
    }
    else if (wpm.DisplayMode == WebPartManager.EditDisplayMode)
    {
        myControl.Attributes.Add("style", "display: block");
    }
}
```

This works, but if I have two **same** webparts on **same** page and put one webpart is edit mode it shows the panel in both webparts. It seems the `OnPreRender` event code runs for both webparts on page.

I even tried writing code as `this.myControl.Attributes.Add("style", "display: block");` but it still didn't work.

I want the `OnPreRender` code to run only on its webpart and not modify the other webaprt on page. How can I resolve this? Is there any better (or preferred) way to do it?

NOTE: I need to use `display: none` because the panel would be accessed via JavaScript.

*PS: This is a cross post from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/153745/20540) as I did not get any satisfactory* answers.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same on the page load, and it works for me just fine .. (page has about 10 WP and only 1 behaves differently in the edit mode.)

Maybe what you mean is that you have 2 SAME webparts on the page? Then I guess both webparts will behave equally because WebPartManager.DisplayMode returns you the mode of the page, not the webpart. (see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartmanager.browsedisplaymode(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: maybe wpm.SelectedWebPart and help somehow.

Comment: Yes. I mean SAME Web part.